# Need to show NULL as a value of missing attributes in a separate row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a table in MSSQL 17 like below:

```
Attribute   Value   Code
Country     Canada  AA
Source      EFT     AA
Manager     Ahmad   AA
Source      EFT     BB
Manager     Mike    BB
Country     Brazil  CC
Source      Cash    CC
```

I need all the codes have the same number of rows, showing the same attributes where the value should be NULL if it does not exist in the table. The output I am looking for:

```
Attribute   Value   Code
Country     Canada  AA
Source      EFT     AA
Manager     Ahmad   AA
Country     NULL    BB
Source      EFT     BB
Manager     Mike    BB
Country     Brazil  CC
Source      Cash    CC
Manager     NULL    CC
```

Can you please help me? Apprecited!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and then a `left join` to bring in the existing values:

```
select a.attribute, t.value, c.code
from (select distinct code from t) c cross join
     (select distinct attribute from t) a left join
     t
     on c.code = t.code and a.attribute = t.attribute
```